# Find N objects in Array which have the max value in a property using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, find

I have an array of objects and one of the fields is the 'score' of those objects.

I know how to get the object which have the max value:

```
array.max_by do |element|
  element.score
end
```

But how would I get the N (for example 3) objects (ordered) which have the biggest scores?  Taking into account that it might be that the array has less than N elements.

EDITED:

So, for example:

`[{score:10}, {score:5}, {score:7}, {score:8}]` and N=3

Should return: `[{score:10}, {score:8}, {score:7}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
max = arr.max_by{|e| e.score}
max_all = arr.find_all{|e| e.score==max}.first(3)
```

**update**

```
ar = [{score:10}, {score:5}, {score:7}, {score:8}]
p ar.sort_by{|e| -e[:score]}.first(3)
# => [{:score=>10}, {:score=>8}, {:score=>7}]
```

Comment: With this approach if the array would contain [{ score: 10}, { score: 5}, {score: 9}, {score: 4}], it would just return {score:10} right? I need the top N objects with biggest scores. I have edited my question to put it more clear.

Comment: @HommerSmith That you should mention first.. :) Now your last edit..shows that you should accept *sawa's* answer... :)

Comment: Thanks Arup Rakshit. I have a question, What is the "-" in -e[:score]?

Comment: @HommerSmith Otherwise ,you need to do `reverse` method,but `-` do that in the first place..

Comment: I think if you implement your own sort, it will be more efficient.  The rest of the array does not need to be sorted.  If you are using a bubble sort, you only have to compare all the elements with the highest 3 (or other fixed low number).  If you are to do the merge sort, you only have to merge the top 3 of each of the lists that are longer than 3.  I think in either case, this essentially takes your performance from O(n log n) or worse down to O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I think @ArupRakshit answer is correct, i would edit it a bit though.

```
max = arr.max_by{|i| i.score}
max_all = arr.find_all{|i| i.score==max}
```

or

```
max_all = arr.select{|i| i.score == max}
```

This is because there is no fixed number of output as mentioned by @HommerSmith it maybe 3 or less or more, we just need to find the max string and all those string with equal length

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 2.2.0, [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) can take an optional integer argument that makes it return an array of entries instead of a single entry, so this code works:

```
records = [{score:10}, {score:5}, {score:7}, {score:8}]
p records.max_by(3) { |n| n[:score] }.sort_by { |n| -n[:score] }
# [{:score=>10}, {:score=>8}, {:score=>7}]
```

The documentation for `max_by` doesn't give us any guarantee on how the returned array will be sorted, so we have to sort it ourselves, which is kind of sad.

This answer is not much better than Arup's answer, except for possible efficiency gains because the Ruby interpreter does not need to sort the entire list, which would be a big benefit if your list is large.